# issue while configuring SSL for existing sharepoint web-application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ssl

Can someone provide working guide for configuring or extending an existing SharePoint web application to internet zone and activating SSL(https://) enabled URL?

We are experiencing a unknown issue when we are activating SSL on existing web-application.

We are taking help from below URL:
     https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2013/01/20/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013/

Thanks

Comment: What is the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: We are using self signing certificate for dev environment. 1. The certificate for this site expires in 2017 or later, and the certificate chain contains a certificate signed using SHA-1.

Comment: 2. There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).

Comment: First issue is fine as we are working on dev and self signing certificate are not supported any more as per Microsoft but second error is not known. Maybe we are making mistakes while extending existing web application or while binding the IIS website.

Comment: This link may help you: https://griffindocs.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/sharepoint-2013-how-to-add-ssl-to-a-web-application/

Comment: Followed the same: Extended web- app and activated SSL after that added self signed certificate to newly created web site in IIS on port 443 still same the certificate error.

Comment: @ArunBhandari: under IIS server certificates, what is the value for Issued To [http://www.screencast.com/t/2TTwKm8n](http://www.screencast.com/t/2TTwKm8n) for SSL cert you are using for SharePoint? And what is the actual url you are using, when opening SharePoint site in a browser?

Comment: Sorry I am not able to access the provided URL. I am creating self signed certificate(providing name and certificate store for new certificate as 'Personal') in IIS  directly under server certificate. I am using my extend web-app url directly to access the site ex:       https://xyz. domain

Comment: issue resolved, Self signed certificate 'Issued to'(which is common name CN of certificate), should same as your host header.

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved, Self signed certificate column Issued to which is common name CN of certificate, should same as your host header. Self signed certificate should be created through power shell while creating from IIS option for desired CN is not there.